# How to redirect user after successful login?

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

Update:
After implementing the below suggestion by Rob Sedgwick, it has become apparent that the redirect only works when the user manually "F5" refreshers the browser (Chrome). What I need to achieve is that this happens automatically in the code so the redirect happens without the user having to hot refresh. Thanks for help with this last part.

At the moment ManageTodosView from what I understand is the first action after the user has been logged in. It prints a list of to do items set up by the user. A working example can be found here http://parseplatform.github.io/Todo/ and the code is https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Todo

I'm using to code to really get user logins to work, I'm not to worries about what the output of the rest of the code is because the long term plan will be to remove it, for the time being its helpful to keep in place to show that the app functioning correctly.

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Todo) as a base to build a web app. At the moment, once the user is logged in, they are displayed data on the same page.

I want to be able to change this so that after they login, the user is redirected to a different page and the information is then displayed to them there.

The reason for this is that the index page is just a landing/login page and I want to redirect them to a more structured HTML page with menus, etc.

Within the JS code, do I just put in a redirect, something like:

```
self.location="top.htm";
```

to this area of the code?

```
// The main view for the app
  var AppView = Parse.View.extend({
    // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
    // the App already present in the HTML.
    el: $("#todoapp"),

    initialize: function() {
      this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
      if (Parse.User.current()) {
        new ManageTodosView();
      } else {
        new LogInView();
      }
    }
  });
```

I have added the JS code to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/y62SL/)

Comment: Hi Dano , thanks for the mention, was hoping you could provide more info related to what 'manageTodosView' does. Did you try replacing it completely ? Is this a single page app ? What do the folks that made the application say ? It's always going to be hard for folks on SO to understand what an application does without more detail sorry.

Comment: I've tried to update based on your comments, not sure if it helps, perhaps we could set up a DM if your willing to help further?

Comment: Hi Dano, sorry couldn't help further. Not a regular javascript problem as relates to getting this https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Todo persons code working the way you want it to. Have you considered asking the author for a collaboration / request. That's what git is for. Other than that, you will need to post up more code about the inner workings of this persons code. eg. How are we to know what ManageTodosView() does?. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

To address the issue of the page needing a manual fresh before the redirect works, insert

```
window.location.href="/someurl";
```

into the following code section within the todoe.js file and comment out the new ManageTodosView(); code.

```
      Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
        success: function(user) {
window.location.href="user_home.html";          
//new ManageTodosView();
          self.undelegateEvents();
          delete self;
        },
```

---

---

Comment: cheers that worked, the only thing at the moment is I need to refresh the page before it goes to the new url. Is there something I can put in Js that auto refreshers the page?

Comment: window.location.reload() is the command to reload the current page from the server.  you can't do both though. ( once you leave the page, you leave the part of the script ) Add some more detail to the question about the whole job ?

Comment: I've tried to update based on your comments, not sure if it helps, perhaps we could set up a DM if your willing to help further?

Comment: Rob, I solved this and have updated the answer, cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also

window.open('url','_parent');

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a [more robust template](https://github.com/priley86/parse-marionette-todo) for integrating Parse Todo samples with real apps. 'Marionette' offers lots of value in real world.

If you take the time to look over the app's structure and then look at the ['loginSuccess'](https://github.com/priley86/parse-marionette-todo/blob/master/App/js/pages/login/views/LoginView.js) function (scroll to very bottom of link), its pretty straightforward to redirect. You can either use the router as shown OR you can use the Marionette aggregated events which would look like:

```
    vent.trigger('header:loggedIn', _user);

somewhere else in any module within the app....

    vent.on('header:loggedIn', function (user) {
        that.setViewNew(user);
            }); 

...

        setViewNew : function (user) {
    User = user;            
    var viewOptionsUser = {
        collection : this.roleList,
             events : {
        'keypress #new-todo':   'createTaskOnEnter'},
         parentUser : User};

    this.headerRegion.show(new HeaderView(viewOptionsUser));        
    this.mainRegion.show(new RoleRoleListCompositeView(viewOptionsUser));
        }
```

Comment: Cheers ?rob Rowntree I will take a look, could you just let me know what you mean by a more "robust" template?

Comment: read anything by derick bailey... http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/17/managing-a-modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette/    for info on robust.... he wrote marionette.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this to redirect your user

```
window.location = 'www.google.com'
```